How to upload an attachment while creating a new record in ZOHO CRM
I am using C# SDK to create new records in Zoho CRM. However I am not able to upload attachment from local drive into attachment field while setting field parameters. However once the record is created, I use the RecordID to upload an attachment in the next step. Is there a way to do both in same step? The API has a FileDetail class but that doesnt seem to work with uploading attachment.
Thank you,
Usman
I have used FileDetails class but it doesn't expose any property to read the file from local directory for uploading.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

This is my code List fileDetailsList = new List();
FileDetails fileDetail = new FileDetails();
fileDetail.FileId = "SOME_FILE_ID_REQUIRED";
fileDetailsList.Add(fileDetail);
recordTemp.AddKeyValue("CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME", fileDetailsList);
